# Android ListPreference checkbox doesn't show selected item

Tags: android

Room 2 Item is selected but it doesn't display a filled circle. 
I can't figure out why it doesn't show the "animation".
What have I missed?

[image: Emulator view of the error]

Sorry that there isn't code here, I had problem adding all my source code, since the question/problem is obvious and there isn't much to write, any way... the problem was with the styles :

Problem is fixed this way:
styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorBlue</item>

        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorBlue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

buggy styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">Bad Value Here</item>


    </style>



</resources>
```

with the fix it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Where is your source code?

Comment: stackoverflow didn't let me add my source code, since it was more than the text.. I found the problem, I'll add to the question.